# How can I check my JSON object contains a string?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am using SSJS to check if the variable `event` in my JSON object contains a string but am struggling to get it working.

Here is my code

```
var jsonpost = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
var payload = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonpost);
if(payload.eventname.includes('part of a string')) {
 // do something
....
```

When I execute this I get a generic string:

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the issue is that [.includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) is actually part of ECMAScript 6 which is above the current level of SFMC SSJS (ECMAScript 3 is a good baseline). So this is likely causing an issue as it is not a recognized function.

I would look at utilizing [.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) instead to check for this substring.

e.g.

```
var jsonpost = Platform.Request.GetPostData(),
    payload = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonpost),
    eventName = payload.eventname;

if(eventName.indexOf('part of a string') > -1) {
   // do something
}
```

indexOf() will return the index (count of char from beginning of string) of the start of this substring value you are searching for. If it does not exist, it will return `-1`, so anything above that means that the substring exists.